# Changing Linux file names to NTFS-compatible file names

Tags: command-line, bash, ntfs, batch-rename, filename

I must create a bash shell to rename the file names in a directory structure. In case the file name contains `\` or `:` or a space it should be translated to `_`, `_`, and `-` respectively. I'm trying to use a loop with the commands "for" and "find", but it is not working. Any suggestion?

Comment: Why not show us what you actually tried; ie. how did you actually use `for` and `find`, what error message(s) you obtained, so we can provide help with your actual code.

Comment: There is a `rename` command that does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

With Perl's [`rename`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/prename.1.html):

```
rename -n 'y/\\: /__\-/ if -f' *
```

... where `-n` is for a dry-run (to actually rename files, remove it or change it to `-v` for verbosity), `y` will translate each character in the search list `\\:`  (that is an escaped backslash `\`, a colon `:` and a space  ) into the corresponding character in the replacement list `__\-` (that is an underscore `_`, another underscore `_` and an escaped hyphen `-`) and `if -f` will work only on files excluding directories from the rename process.

**Notice** that you can expand both lists as long as every character in the search list has its corresponding character in the replacement list in the right order and as long as you escape any character that needs escaping in a RegEx context and not in a shell context as the quotes will protect those characters from the shell.

**Notice** as well that this will not work on hidden files that start with a dot `.` unless you explicitly set Bash's `dotglob` option.

Answer (score 0):

Create a script, e.g. `translate.sh`:

```bash
#! /bin/bash
old=$1
new=${1//:/_}     # Replace colons by underscores.
new=${new// /-}   # Replace spaces by dashes.
new=${new//\\/_}  # Replace backslashes by underscores.

if [[ $new = $old ]] ; then  # No change, skip this one.
    exit
fi

if [[ -e $new ]] ; then
    echo "Cannot rename $old, $new already exists" >&2
else
    mv "$old" "$new"
fi
```

Then run

```bash
find . -exec ./translate.sh {} \;
```